# scraping all images, next page button and then next button again

Tags: python, web-scraping, pagination

I'm trying to **scrape** all the images from a site, but it's hard for me to try because of the pagination by using next button problem.

Here's the website I want to **scrape** .

```
http://img.imyimy.com/mengmeizi/
```

As you can see at the bottom, this site does not tell me the maximum number of pages, but keeps me pressing the next page button.

```
<a class="next page-numbers" href="/mengmeizi/index_2.html"><span>下一页»</span></a>
```

And when you open a link to any individual image container, there are images again on several secondary pages. This is also a structure that requires pressing the next page button.

```
http://img.imyimy.com/mengmeizi/19039.html
<a href="/mengmeizi/19039_2.html"><span>下一页</span></a>
```

In conclusion, if I want to download all the images of each album, I have to code the repetitive looping syntax, but I'm a beginner, so I don't know how to rotate them using the next page button and then do next button looping again.

I'm not asking you to tell me the whole code.

Please give me some examples to show me how to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get all `<img>` links from all pages, you can use next example (it will increase page number and format the URL in format `http://img.imyimy.com/mengmeizi/index_<page number>.html`. If server returns `404` HTTP error code, it will break the loop.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

first_page_url = "http://img.imyimy.com/mengmeizi/"
page_n_url = "http://img.imyimy.com/mengmeizi/index_{}.html"

page = 1
while True:
    if page == 1:
        url = first_page_url
    else:
        url = page_n_url.format(page)

    print(f"Downloading {url=}")

    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        break

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    for img in soup.select("img[data-original]"):
        print(img["data-original"])

    page += 1
```

Prints:

```
Downloading url='http://img.imyimy.com/mengmeizi/'
http://imgs.ttyysp.com/2021-01-11/0212608.jpg
http://imgs.ttyysp.com/2021-01-11/0212107.jpg
http://imgs.ttyysp.com/2021-01-11/0211813.jpg
http://imgs.ttyysp.com/2021-01-11/0212017.jpg
http://imgs.ttyysp.com/2021-01-11/0211587.jpg
http://imgs.ttyysp.com/2021-01-11/0211742.jpg
http://imgs.ttyysp.com/2021-01-11/0211372.jpg

...and so on.
```

---

EDIT: To get URLs of subpages:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

first_page_url = "http://img.imyimy.com/mengmeizi/"
page_n_url = "http://img.imyimy.com/mengmeizi/index_{}.html"

page = 1
while True:
    if page == 1:
        url = first_page_url
    else:
        url = page_n_url.format(page)

    print(f"Downloading {url=}")

    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        break

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    for a in soup.select("a:has(img[data-original])"):
        print("http://img.imyimy.com" + a["href"])

    page += 1
```

Prints:

```
Downloading url='http://img.imyimy.com/mengmeizi/'
http://img.imyimy.com/mengmeizi/19077.html
http://img.imyimy.com/mengmeizi/19076.html
http://img.imyimy.com/mengmeizi/19074.html
http://img.imyimy.com/mengmeizi/19071.html
http://img.imyimy.com/mengmeizi/19069.html
http://img.imyimy.com/mengmeizi/19068.html

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But how do I also loop sub pages? (this is the point) images I want to download are all saved in sub-pages.

Comment: @Peters7 Use the same principle as iterating the main page - increase the page untill you get `404` error status, then end the iteration.